# How to Export Data From SQL Server to CSV File using sql statement

Tags: sql-server, export-to-csv

So what i am trying to do is using query inset data in CSV file with headers i know this not the right way i also tried using "bcp" on sql but it spiking the headers as well putting everything in one column

```
bulk insert "C:\New folder\s.csv"
from [D].[user]
with (fieldterminator = ',', rowterminator = '\n')
go
```

Sources should be sql Query 
Output result should be a .CSV file with Headers

Comment: What was the `bcp` command you ran? Normally, with `bcp` you would run the command in command line, not in SQL.

Comment: EXEC xp_cmdshell bcp "SELECT * FROM [Dept].[Departments]" queryout "C:\New folder\s.csv" -T -c -t,

Comment: That should be in your question, not the comments. Why are you running the command from SQL Server, rather than command line, and why is the command not in single quotes (and why does it end with a comma (`,`))?

Comment: Try fieldterminator = '\t' instead of ','. Or fieldterminator = ';' instead of ','. It depends on the excel's default setting. Or else you can try opening the CSV that your existing code is generating and goto to Data tab -> Text to Column -> Select Delimited -> check Comma and click on Finish